# How to test delete instance in Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Running Django, I have a view to delete logged-in user on POST request.

```
@login_required
def delete_user(request):
    """Delete user from DB."""
    if request.method == "POST":
        get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.pk).delete()
        messages.success(request, _("User deleted!"), extra_tags="success")
        return redirect("home")
    return render(request, "accounts/delete-user.html")
```

HTML form is:

```
            <form method="POST" name="delete-user-form" id="delete-user-form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button class="mt-4 btn btn-danger" name="delete-user-btn" id="delete-user-btn" type="submit">{% translate "Delete my profile" %}</button>
            </form>
```

My test class with user:

```
class ViewsWithLoggedInUserTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        User.objects.create_user(
            email="test@test.com",
            password="test",
            first_name="TestFirstName",
            last_name="TestLastName",
            hometown="Kiev",
            facebook_link="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1000",
            contacts="+380991111111",
            start_coordinates="50.45, 30.52",
            avatar="avatar/default_avatar.jpg",
        )
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.get(email="test@test.com")
        self.client.force_login(user=self.user)
        print("setUp")

    def test_delete_user_post(self):
        """Test delete user post."""
        response = self.client.post(path=reverse("delete_user"))
        self.assertFalse(self.user)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertRedirects(response, expected_url=reverse("home"))
```

I can not undrstand how to test this function, my `test_delete_user_post` gives me

```
AssertionError: <User: test@test.com> is not false
```

Comment: It's probably because **self.user** is stored in memory for the client.. Try to query the DB and see if it's still in there: `self.assertTrue(User.objects.filter(pk=self.user.pk).count()==0)` ..and just imo, I'd move the other two (status+redirect checks) above the user check, as those two failing would already tell you the user wasn't deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (less complex/ more obvious?) alternative to xyres' answer

```
# setUp created self.user which this test should delete ...
def test_delete_user_post(self):
    response = self.client.post(path=reverse("delete_user"))
    self.assertFalse( User.objects.filter( pk=self.user.pk).exists() )
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because the variable `self.user` still holds the previously assigned value.

Use the [`refresh_from_db()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db) method to update the variable with fresh value.

Also, to test deletion, you have to test if the `DoesNotExist` exception is raised or not. Testing using `assertFalse` will not work.

Code example:

```py
def test_delete_user_post(self):
        response = self.client.post(path=reverse("delete_user"))
        
        with self.assertRaises(User.DoesNotExist):
            # Django will try to fetch the new value from the database
            # but since it's been deleted, DoesNotExist exception
            # will be raised
            self.user.refresh_from_db()

        ...
```